# Facebook share button error 401 authorization required

Tags: facebook, share

Ok, I have this problem with the facebook share button on my site. For one week I was having a password on my site and two days ago I removed it. However when I click on a facebook share button on my site I get this error: 
***401 Authorization Required  This server could not verify...***
It looks like the facebook crawler is recognising my site as it is with password but it's not. I tried the debugging tool. The error that was found was this:
***Bad Response Code    URL returned a bad HTTP response code.***
And it's not recognisin my meta tags.

Inferred Property   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Inferred Property   The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Inferred Property   The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

But I have this tags on the page I want to share. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Did you click “fetch new scrape information” in debug tool, so that it actually makes a new request? Otherwise, you might simply be looking at cached data.

Comment: Thank you I think I solved my problem :)